# Number formatting exception when accepting an integer

Tags: java, formatting

I'm getting a number format exception. I don't know why.

```
    int t;
    t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

Comment: You're getting this because the String read in is not an int. Please show the exception stacktrace message, and it will tell you why as it will tell you what the String is that you're trying to parse.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because it can be solved using basic debugging. Save the input from the console in a variable and look at its value before trying to parse it, you'll know soon enough what went wrong. This question offers little value to future readers.

Answer (score 2):

You must have passed an invalid string to `parseInt` from your `BufferedReader.readLine()` method. That method [is designed such that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

> The characters in the string must all be decimal digits, except that the first character may be an ASCII minus sign '-' ('\u002D') to indicate a negative value or an ASCII plus sign '+' ('\u002B') to indicate a positive value.

For example:

- valid: `-1`
- valid: `1`
- invalid: `1.1`
- invalid: `1\r\n` (1 followed by a new line character)

You could try calling `trim()` on the `bi.readLine()` output, or first checking it against a regular expression to ensure it actually contains a valid string representation of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that there are no trailing zeros and that the string only contains one integer.

```
int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());
```